# NullPointer When Passing Data from DialogFragment to Activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, fragment

I am trying to prompt the user to create a username via a DialogFragment.

When I display the dialogfragment, I want the user to enter a username, and then I pass that username back to the activity, and then write to Firebase:

DialogFragment:

```
public class DisplayNameDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

//TODO: Is this going to cause compile-time exception in these versions?
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_name_dialog, null);
    final EditText displayName = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.DISPLAY_NAME_LABEL);
    builder.setView(mView);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_done, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            String displayNameEntered = displayName.getText().toString();
                 listener.onFinishEditDialog(displayNameEntered);
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}

public static interface EditNameDialogListener {
    public abstract void onFinishEditDialog(String inputText);
}

private EditNameDialogListener listener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        this.listener = (EditNameDialogListener)getActivity();
    } catch (final ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString() + "must implement listener");
     }
   }
 }
```

Receiving Activity:

```
public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DisplayNameDialogFragment.EditNameDialogListener{
private static final String TAG = "SignupActivity";

@Bind(R.id.input_email)
EditText _emailText;
@Bind(R.id.input_password)
EditText _passwordText;
@Bind(R.id.btn_signup)...........

@Override
public void onFinishEditDialog(String inputText) {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    UserProfileChangeRequest m = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
            .setDisplayName(inputText).build();
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    user.updateProfile(m);
    Log.v("INPUT_TEXT", user.getDisplayName());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), inputText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent toHome = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(toHome);
      }
 }
```

I am receiving a NullPointer and unsure why:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                                                                         at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:118)
                                                                         at com.troychuinard.fanpolls.SignupActivity.onFinishEditDialog(SignupActivity.java:367)
                                                                         at com.troychuinard.fanpolls.Fragment.DisplayNameDialogFragment$1.onClick(DisplayNameDialogFragment.java:39)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:163)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Comment: I've not used Firebase yet, but I would imagine `updateProfile()` is asynchronous, which means the display name will not have been updated by the time you try to retrieve it on the next line.

Comment: Yeah, if you check [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#updateProfile(com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest)), it returns a [`Task`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task), on which you'd set a listener.

Comment: Got it, do you believe that is causing the nullpointer?

Comment: I believe it's causing `user.getDisplayName()` to return null right there. The actual Exception is coming from `Log`, which doesn't like nulls. Phan's answer is technically correct, but doesn't really help much.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Log.v("INPUT_TEXT", user.getDisplayName());
```

to

```
Log.v("INPUT_TEXT", "" + user.getDisplayName());
```

Error `java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message` mean your message in `Log` must != null

Comment: What does the + denote?

Comment: Does it mean the display name is null though?

Comment: According to the `logcat` error message, I do think so

Comment: Odd, I am using it in another activity and I am capturing the display name via the dialogfragment with no issues

Comment: This is another problem, currently your problem in this question is solve. Now you need to solve another problem is why your display name is null